# calculate svd - example with roots

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Do an Singular Value Decomposition of

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I have tried to find it following the [regular algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Example) but failed. If someone showed me how do this example, I might get it.

Comment: Your link doesn't actually describe an algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
**Step 1:**

Find the spectral decomposition of $AA^*$.  That is, find a diagonal matrix $D$ and unitary matrix $U$ for which
$$
UDU^* = AA^*
$$
To get the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$, take the square root of the entries of $D$, so that we now have
$$
U\Sigma\Sigma^*U^* = AA^*
$$
In this case, you should have
$$
\Sigma = \pmatrix{2&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0}
$$
And a valid $U$ would be
$$
U = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
**Step 2:**

Find a unitary matrix $V$ such that, with $U$ and $\Sigma$ as above, we have
$$
U\Sigma V^* = A
$$
Or, equivalently,
$$
U\Sigma = A V
$$
For the $U$ I've chosen, a valid corresponding $V$ is
$$
V = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\pmatrix
{
1&0&0&-1\\
0&1&-1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&0
}
$$

Comment: I know the theory, I can't do this example.

Comment: At what point do you get stuck?  Can you find $U$ and $\Sigma$?

Comment: I did not know the dimesions of the matrices $\Sigma$ and $U$ but I think you solution made me get it. Thanks.